# cuda + opencv Illegal memory access

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, opencv3.0

I am new in Cuda programming.

What I want to do is just a function what realize the arctan of a matrix.
In order to know how to interface with OpenCV I inpire my code from OpenCV's bilateral filter implementation (the one of cudaimgproc).

So I wrote atan.hpp :

```
#ifndef ATAN_HPP
#define ATAN_HPP

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>


namespace support
{

namespace cuda
{
void atan(cv::InputArray _src,cv::OutputArray _dst,cv::cuda::Stream& stream = cv::cuda::Stream::Null());
}

}

#endif // ATAN_HPP
```

Then atan.cpp

```
#include "atan.hpp"

#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudev/common.hpp>



namespace support
{

namespace cuda
{

namespace device
{
template<class _Ty>
void atan_(const cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb& src, cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb dst,cudaStream_t);

}

void atan(cv::InputArray _src, cv::OutputArray _dst, cv::cuda::Stream &stream)
{

    CV_Assert(
                (_src.depth() == _src.type()) &&
                (_src.isMat() || _src.isUMat() || ((_src.kind() & cv::_InputArray::CUDA_GPU_MAT) == cv::_InputArray::CUDA_GPU_MAT)) &&
                (_dst.isMat() || _dst.isUMat() || ((_dst.kind() & cv::_OutputArray::CUDA_GPU_MAT) == cv::_OutputArray::CUDA_GPU_MAT))
                );

     cv::cuda::GpuMat src;
     cv::cuda::GpuMat buf;

    int type = _src.isMat() ? 0 : _src.isUMat() ? 1 : 2;

    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        cv::Mat tmp = _src.getMat();

        src.upload(tmp);

    }
        break;

    case 1:
    {
        cv::UMat tmp = _src.getUMat();
        cv::Mat tmp2;

        tmp.copyTo(tmp2);

        src.upload(tmp2);
    }
        break;

    case 2:
        src = _src.getGpuMat();
        break;

    }



    buf.create(src.size(),src.type());
//    buf.upload(cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(),src.type()));

    switch (buf.depth())
    {
    case CV_8U:
        device::atan_<uchar>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_8S:
        device::atan_<char>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_16U:
        device::atan_<ushort>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_16S:
        device::atan_<short>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_32S:
        device::atan_<int>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_32F:
        device::atan_<float>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    case CV_64F:
        device::atan_<double>(src,buf, cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::getStream(stream));
        break;
    }




    type = _dst.isMat() ? 0 : _dst.isUMat() ? 1 : 2;

    switch(type)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        cv::Mat tmp;

        buf.download(tmp);
    }
        break;

    case 1:
    {
        cv::Mat tmp;
        cv::UMat tmp2;

        buf.download(tmp);

        tmp.copyTo(tmp2);
    }
        break;

    case 2:
        buf.copyTo(_dst);
        break;

    }

}

}

}
```

and at last atan .cu

```
#include <opencv2/core/cuda/common.hpp>


typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;

namespace support
{

namespace cuda
{

namespace device
{

template<class _Ty>
__global__ void katan(const  cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<_Ty>& src, cv::cuda::PtrStep<_Ty> dst)
{

    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if( (y>=src.rows) && (x>=src.cols) )
        return;


        dst(y,x) = ::atan(static_cast<double>(src(y,x)));

}


template<class _Ty>
void atan_(const  cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb& src, cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb dst,cudaStream_t stream)
{

    dim3 block (32, 8);
    dim3 grid ( cv::cuda::device::divUp (src.cols, block.x),  cv::cuda::device::divUp (src.rows, block.y));


    cudaSafeCall( cudaFuncSetCacheConfig (katan<_Ty>, cudaFuncCachePreferL1) );
    katan<<<grid, block, 0, stream>>>(( cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<_Ty>)src, ( cv::cuda::PtrStepSz<_Ty>)dst);
    cudaSafeCall ( cudaGetLastError () );

    if (stream == 0)
        cudaSafeCall( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

}

}

}

}

#define INSTANTIATE_ATAN(T) \
    template void support::cuda::device::atan_<T>(const  cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb&,  cv::cuda::PtrStepSzb, cudaStream_t);

INSTANTIATE_ATAN(uchar)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(char)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(ushort)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(short)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(int)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(float)
INSTANTIATE_ATAN(double)
```

I create a minimum exemple in order to check if it work or not :

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>



#include "atan.hpp"


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    typedef float type;

    cv::Mat_<type> input(32,32);
    cv::Mat_<type> output(input.size());

    std::for_each(input.begin(),input.end(),[&](type& v){ v = cv::theRNG().uniform(1.,100.);});

    std::transform(input.begin(),input.end(),output.begin(),[&](const type& v){ return std::atan(v); });


    cv::cuda::GpuMat buf;

    buf.upload(input);

    support::cuda::atan(buf,buf);

    cv::Mat tmp;

    buf.download(tmp);

    std::cout<<tmp<<std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It compile well but when I try to execute I have this exception :

OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (an illegal memory access was encountered) in atan_, file ../bilateral/atan.cu, line 51
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  ../bilateral/atan.cu:51: error: (-217) an illegal memory access was encountered in function atan_

A fast research on google let me understood the origin of this error could be various.

I would like to understand what's wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `katan` kernel, `src` should be passed by value instead of by const reference. Remember that at the caller side, `src` resides in the host memory side, so passing by reference will not incur any host to device memory copy, which means that in the `katan` kernel, `src` is also at the host side. You cannot access host memory in the kernel code. Passing by value will imply an implicit host to device memory copy, so it will be okay.

And I believe that it should be `||` in `if( (y>=src.rows) && (x>=src.cols) )` ?

Comment: Effectively you are wright.
That fix the issue.
Thanks a lot :).